# Reputation: questions AND answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

How many reputation points have I gained from the *questions* that I have asked and how many reputation points have I earned from *answering* people?

I always try to keep a 1:5 ratio, just to avoid asking more questions. But there is no feature where the user can see their total segregated reputation.

---

*I got my answer, but I believe there can be a much easier way to do this. Maybe we can have a small bar on the profile page at the bottom where we can display the stats. Firing a query to know your stats each time becomes a little tedious.
@codeMagic: thanks for the answer.*

Comment: RE: your edit, you can create a profile on [data.SE] and you can save your favorite queries, so you can always find the ones you like quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How many reputation points have I gained from the questions that I have asked and how many reputation points have I earned from answering people?

I guess you [want this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7714/question-rep-vs-answer-rep). Just enter your user id and it will give you the stats. I think this is an awesome tool to know what your stats are for curiosity but I wouldn't worry too much about the results.

> I always try to keep a 1:5 ratio, just to avoid asking more questions.

Personally, I've never thought about the ratio. If you have a valid question then ask it. When you can answer something then answer it.

**Get your user id**

Click on your user name at the top. On your profile page, in the search box you will see "user:" after the colon is your id. It is also in the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). Below. Yours is 2463734, for example

[image]

**Your results**

[image]

Comment: i know i am using the site correctly..but still i wanted to know my stats..how do i get ny user id? and 1:5 thing is something i always keep in my mind..i do the same as you do

Comment: See my edit. I wasn't insinuating anything, I was just unclear on why you were asking.

Comment: that is giving me no results ..just a blank row.And I am just curious about how many answer i have given.Just wanted to know it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I have edited with the results I got with your user id

Comment: Sorry my images kind of suck but that should show you where the information is.

Comment: If you still can't see the data, let me know. Make sure you are **just** entering the digits from your user id.

Comment: i am not getting the data..i did enter the numeric id only

Comment: Can you edit and post an image of the results you are getting and of the page where you are entering it? With the rep you have, it seems to be giving me your correct results.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: Where are you getting that id from? I have 2463734 for you...

Comment: codeMagic that's his Meta user id.  @Time_to_leave_earth use the user id that codeMagic has provided.  Your user id is different on each site.

Comment: alright...got the point

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks. I just noticed that but didn't respond in time